# Jumping ropes for table tennis?

Tags: training, table-tennis, jump-rope

I am new to table tennis and I really would like to improve my footwork. Can jumping ropes be beneficial for my footwork, or are there better ways to improve footwork?

My initial goal was to use jump ropes as a warm-up exercise but doing some research on the internet showed that it is also a type of sport and has lots of benefits. I want to find out whether jumping rope can bring some benefits to my table tennis play, namely, to my footwork. On the other hand, I don't want to mess up footwork either without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping rope in general will improve your coordination, agility, balance and endurance. It is common to see boxers doing it for the benefits mentioned above and it is also a great warm-up exercise with minimal injury risk.

With that said, a good warm up could consist of jumping rope for about 2-3 min to elevate your heart rate, some side to side movements or lateral shuffles to prime your body for the game, and some dynamic stretches to prevent injury during your game.